# Prove that a matrix is not diagonalizable for any scalars $a$, $b$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I need to prove that
\begin{align*}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 & 0\\
0 & a & 0\\
0 & 0 & b\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

is not diagonalizable for any scalars $a$ and $b$.

I've tried just finding the eigenvalues to start with, and I end up with the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=a$ with multiplicity 2 and $\lambda_2=b$ with mult. 1. Then I find that the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace for $\lambda_1$ has dimension 1 and the corresponding eigenspace for $\lambda_2$ has dimension 1 as well. Since the dimension of the eigenspace of $\lambda_1=a$ doesn't match its multiplicity, then the original matrix is not diagonalizable. Is this correct..?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is wrong.  The dimensions of the eigenspaces are $1$, not $2$.

Comment: Oh, right. Since for both eigenvalues, rank($A-\lambda I)=2$, then the dimension are $3-2=1$. So then the multiplicity does not match this value for $\lambda = a$, so the original matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable. Is this correct now?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.